# Can't tap text fields or buttons in iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm not sure why I can't tap on `Login` nor `Signup`.  It's giving this bluish greenish color like the below picture.  I know it's something very simple, but I just can't seem to spot it.
 [image].

Here's `index.ios.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Application from './pages/Application';
import store from './redux';
import api from './utilities/api';

export default class DApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: true
        }
        console.log("something");
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        api.getData().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.data
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            console.log("The data is: " + this.state.data);
        } else {
            console.log("Else got executed");
        }

        return (

            <Provider store={store}>
                <Application/>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DApp', () => DApp);
```

Here's `Login.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ScrollView, Text, TextInput, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { login } from '../redux/actions/auth';
import {AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser, CognitoUserAttribute, CognitoUserPool} from '../lib/aws-cognito-identity';

const awsCognitoSettings = {
    UserPoolId: 'some id',
    ClientId: 'some id'
};

class Login extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            page: 'Login',
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }

    get alt () { return (this.state.page === 'Login') ? 'SignUp' : 'Login'; }

    handleClick (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(awsCognitoSettings);

        // Sign up
        if (this.state.page === 'SignUp') {
            const attributeList = [
                new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'email', Value: this.state.userame })
            ];
            userPool.signUp(
                this.state.username,
                this.state.password,
                attributeList,
                null,
                (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        alert(err);
                        this.setState({ username: '', password: '' });
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(`result = ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
                    this.props.onLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password);
                }
            );
        } else {
            const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
                Username: this.state.username,
                Password: this.state.password
            });
            const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
                Username: this.state.username,
                Pool: userPool
            });
            cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
                onSuccess: (result) => {
                    console.log(`access token = ${result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()}`);
                    this.props.onLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password);
                },
                onFailure: (err) => {
                    alert(err);
                    this.setState({ username: '', password: '' });
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    togglePage (e) {
        this.setState({ page: this.alt });
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{padding: 20}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 27}}>{this.state.page}</Text>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder='Email Address'
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoFocus={true}
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                    value={this.state.username}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ username: text })} />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder='Password'
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password: text })} />
                <View style={{margin: 7}}/>
                <Button onPress={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} title={this.state.page}/>
                <View style={{margin: 7, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text onPress={(e) => this.togglePage(e)} style={{fontSize: 12, color: 'blue'}}>
                        {this.alt}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        width: null,
        height: null,
        flex: 1
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onLogin: (username, password) => { dispatch(login(username, password)); }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: Do you have inspect mode enabled? 
More: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inspector enabled. Do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open the developer menu and disable inspector.

Comment: Wow.... I knew it was simple.  Thanks a lot and I apologize for the silly question.

Comment: Don’t worry about it. Now you know a little bi about how to use the developer menu